# fancontrol in hp spectre x360

Tags: 18.04, 19.10, hp, fancontrol

I recently bought an hp spectre x350 15t df100 ceo. In windows fan works correctly and device is cool all the time, but in ubuntu 19.10 fan start threshold is hi for full-metal laptop (last week I have same situation in ubuntu 18.04 too). I installed `lm-sensors` and get this output:

```bsh
$ sudo pwmconfig
/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

I used `sensors-detect` and already have this in `/etc/modules`:

```bsh
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.


# Generated by sensors-detect on Wed Jul 29 10:57:06 2020
# Chip drivers
coretemp
```

How can I control my laptop fan and lower it's fan start threshold?

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 is EOL (https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2020-July/000258.html) so you should *release-upgrade* asap if you're using 19.10, as Ubuntu 19.10 is now off-topic on this site due to EOL status (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm not kidding, but there is an another feature hp puts in my laptop: whenever, with any temperature, if I flip screen to tablet-mode in ubuntu 19.10, instantly fans start working at maximum speed. I don't care about it's sound and anytime I can do it, but mainly I use my device in laptop-mode style.

Comment: I have exactly same problem in ubuntu 18.04 too @guiverc

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is still supported, however the question indicates you moved to a now *unsupported* and *off-topic* release.

Comment: laptops usually don't have PWM support.  when running sensors-detect, look for anything detected in the SuperIO section.  If nothing is found, you'll have to look for an acpi based solution like thermald.

Comment: Same problem on my HP Spectre 13-4003dx under Kubuntu 20.10 x64. No sensors in Linux 5.8.0-25-generic kernel. ```sudo pwmconfig``` outputs ```/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed``` tried ```acpi_enforce_resources=lax``` to GRUB with no avail. In Windows 10 x64 there is a full thermal info.

Comment: @guiverc @Roey Still no solution. I control my laptop temperature using `stress`. First check temperature, if it's over 75 degree, I stress one cpu core. Too much more battery usage, but I don't have any better idea currently.